# Linux kernel Android

Tags: android, linux, kernel

I am trying to build a kernel module for my Android.

First I need to compile the kernel for phone. My problem is that I don't know which defconfig do I need to use.

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/path/to/arm/compiler XXX_defconfig
```

- My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S5
- Model: SM-G900F
- Current kernel: 3.4.0-9493471

Do you know how I can find this information?

Answer (score 0):

you can start with qcom_defconfig but I think you will need to make a lot of changes to it as that defconfig is for qualcomm's SOCs. 
OR
If you have the shell access on the phone (if you have root access), you can use the config file that is already there under

```
/boot/config-XXX
```

Comment: I have a shell access to the phone and I have root access but I can't find any /boot dir

Comment: if you can run a grep on config file. It is also at times located at /proc/config, I am not exactly sure where it is placed in android kernel but it has to be somewhere

Comment: @Jef42 this might be helpful : https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/kernel/config

Comment: that was a good idea, but because I need to use an older kernel version(3.4.0) I don't have those android config files. So I managed to compile the kernel and kernel module but when I inserted it, it fails.